# e.stopPropagation doesn't work for mouseenter event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div nested in an anchor like this:

```
<a href="www.example.com">
  <div class="nested-div"></div>
</a>
```

I want to prevent the anchor from getting underlined or redirected to www.example.com when I hover or click the nested div.
I thought this should be possible with event.stopPropagation(), but it doesn't work.

I am able to stop the click event when I click on the nested div from redirecting to the href using this:

```
$('.nested-div').ready(function() {
  $('.nested-div').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Now I want to also prevent hovering the nested div from getting the anchor underlined, but this doesn't work:

```
 $('.nested-div').mouseenter(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

To be clear I want hovering the anchor itself to have the underlining, but not when the nested div is hovered. Is this possible?

Comment: It's not javascript that's underlining the element, it's css. You need to add a css rule to your element so it won't be underlined

Comment: "To be clear I want hovering the anchor itself to have the underlining, but not when the nested div is hovered. Is this possible?" This doesn't make sense, as the anchor IS the div, what exactly do you mean by hovering the anchor if you are not hovering the div?

Comment: The div is nested inside the anchor, but not placed over it.

Comment: as mentioned it is the :hover CSS pseudo-class which does that effect on the   anchor element. Example a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by CSS and not any scripting rule. Remove the styles with something like this:

```css
a.nostyle:link {
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: auto;
}

a.nostyle:visited {
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="google.com"><div class="nested-div">test</div></a>
vs
<a href="google.com" class="nostyle"><div class="nested-div">test</div></a>
```

Comment: I'd slightly modify your example so it matches the author structure: a div inside a a

Comment: @Axnyff I could do that, but it doesn't really change anything. That code is just to give an example for the CSS. The CSS will still work.

Comment: I tried adding your code to the css file, then inside the event:   $('a').addClass('nostyle');
But still doesnt work..the link gets underlined

Comment: @blackCode I'm unable to replicate what you're experiencing sadly, could you make a Pen that replicates this behavior?

Comment: @Laif your code snippet works for 'color' and 'cursor'. The link gets a different color and no pointer so it works, but still for some reason hovering the nested div underlines the link. Is there any other property that might be affecting it?

Comment: @blackCode I really can't tell without a reproducible example of what you're experiencing. I recommend using devtools to tell what is causing the underline style

Comment: @Laif got it to work. The status bar on the bottom left corner of the browser still shows "www.google.com" when i hover the nested div, the same way it does when you hover any link. Is there a way to turn this off? Thanks a lot.

Comment: To explain why i need this, I unfortunately can't change the html structure, the nested div has to be inside the anchor, but it needs to behave completely separate from the anchor, in hovering.

Comment: @blackCode Unfortunately there is not, as it is the browser that is taking this action and isn't on your page at all. If you wanted a workaround, you could instead have a script redirect the player to the desired location by treating the "link" as a button, although I'm not sure what will happen if you just fully remove the href. I promise it isn't worth it though, that feature is there to protect users by letting them know where they are being sent.